# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: controller-extension, null-pointer

Can anyone help with this error?

```
    System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

    Class.productdata.getMapOfContent: line 24, column 1
```

Here is the Apex Class. "Line 24" refers to "if(LoopContentData.TagCsv.contains(getTag())) {"

```
public class productdata {

    LIST<ContentVersion> allContentData= [select Available_To__c, IsLatest,ContentModifiedDate, Title, ReasonForChange, VersionNumber, RatingCount, Description, ContentDocumentId, TagCsv, ContentDocument.ParentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE IsLatest=TRUE];
    LIST<CONTENTWORKSPACE> WorkspaceObjects = [SELECT Name, ID FROM CONTENTWORKSPACE];
    MAP<string,LIST<ContentVersion>> MyMapOfContent = new MAP<string,LIST<ContentVersion>>();
    //string prod = [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')].Name;
    string prod;
    product2 myProduct;

    public productdata(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.myProduct = (Product2)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public String getTag(){
        return prod = [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :myProduct.ID].Name;
    }


    public MAP<string,LIST<ContentVersion>> getMapOfContent(){
        for(CONTENTWORKSPACE loopIds : WorkspaceObjects){
            LIST<ContentVersion> theContentVersionMapLoop = new LIST<contentversion>();         
            for(ContentVersion LoopContentData : allContentData){
                if(LoopContentData.ContentDocument.ParentId == loopIds.ID){
                    if(LoopContentData.TagCsv.contains(getTag())) {
                        theContentVersionMapLoop.add(LoopContentData);
                    }
                }
            }
            MyMapOfContent.put(loopIds.Name,theContentVersionMapLoop);
        }
        return MyMapOfContent;
    }

}
```

I know it has something to do with getTag method but I have no idea why. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what line 24 is?

Comment: "Line 24" refers to "if(LoopContentData.TagCsv.contains(getTag())) {" THANKS!

Comment: Is TagCsv null for any of those records?

Comment: Yeah, it very well could be. I'll test that and escape the next few rows if that is the case. Thanks!

Comment: Note: you have SOQL (getTag()) inside of nested loops. You could just reference `myProduct.Name` directly instead of querying for it every iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the reference myProduct.Name directly but when I do I receive this error: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Product2.Name

Comment: @MichaelWelburn you were right (which also explains why I wasn't seeing the error in my sandbox site). I added a line to ensure test if TagCsv != null and it works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelWelburn I want to make sure you get credit for answering this for me, do you want to add an answer and I'll mark it? (this is my first day with SF.stackexchange. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, added below. To @MikeChale's point, you don't want to have that SOQL query inside a loop. It works fine now but once you have additional rows you'll start to run into Governor Limits with the number of queries you can run. Take a look at these best practices: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Comment: @MikeChale Hi Mike, thanks for your comment (good catch), I think this is going to be a big problem for my performance, any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: You can either add it to your VF page in a hidden tag or use the controller method `addFields` http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check to see if TagCsv is null for any of those rows? If you attempt an instance method call on a null value, you'll get the "Attempt to De-Reference a Null Object" error.